# Java: Control thread speed / change delay of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I need some help with threads in java.

I'm currently working on a project, what compiles a class at runtime and invokes it's main method. The class represents a guy in a territory, which is visible as a canvas to the user.
This main method invokes some other methods. Either methods the user typed into an editor or predefined methods from a super class.
The editor content could look like this:

```
main() {
 System.out.println("test users class main");
 takeAll();
 takeAll();
}

public void takeAll() {
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    move();
 takeHoney();
 takeHoney();
 takeHoney();
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    move();
}
```

The above code is what the user later enters into an editor inside the GUI, which will be compiled when he uses a certain button. He is supposed to learn imperative programming.

The methods main, move and takeHoney are defined in a superclass and takeAll is a method defined by the user at runtime.
My program adds the class prefix and compiles the users class.

The user should be able to start, pause, resume, and terminate the main method by clicking some buttons in the GUI.

When I just run the main method all methods finish too fast. The user will only see the result, but not the steps and won't be able to interact while it's runnning.

So far I created a new runnable and started a thread.

```
protagonistMainMethodRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        protagonist.main();
        terminateWasPressed();
    }
};
//.....
Thread thread = new Thread(protagonistMainMethodRunnable);
thread.run();
```

"protagonist" is an instance of the users class, which was compiled at runtime.

I'm not very good with threads and can't find an idea to create a delay after each method call.

Does someone have an idea to create a delay after each method call in the main or even after every method call?

EDIT: The idea from James_D was very helpful. Here is the class that works for my use case:

```
public class OperationQueue {

    private Queue<Runnable> operationQueue = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
    private Timeline timeline;

    public OperationQueue(double delay) {
        timeline = null;
        setDelay(delay);
    }

    public void setDelay(double seconds) { //careful: seconds > 0
        if (timeline != null)
            timeline.stop();
        System.out.println("Set keyframe duration to " + seconds + "         seconds.");
        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(seconds), e -> {
            if (!operationQueue.isEmpty()) {
                operationQueue.remove().run();
            }       
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }

    public Queue<Runnable> getOperationQueue() {
        return operationQueue;
    }

    public void add(Runnable queueItem) {
        this.operationQueue.add(queueItem);
    }
    public void clearQueue() {
        this.operationQueue.clear();
    }
}
```

I moved the timeline to a setter method. In that way you can change the delay at runtime (with a slider for example).

Comment: What GUI library are you using?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I use JavaFX for the GUI

Comment: @ScaryWombat How can I invoke the sleep method after each method? The user should not have to insert it in his class after each call.

Comment: @JWo Sorry your question is not clear

Comment: What are you using to compile your code dynamically?

Comment: @MikaelF Thanks, but this will only create one initial delay. When the delay is over the problem is still the same

Comment: @MikaelF I will add the code from my compiler in a moment to my post above.

Comment: This question is really too broad - this is not a simple problem, and your specification is not very clear. Would it be enough to implement the pauses in each of your "predefined" methods (I assume these are `move()` and `takeHoney()` in the example)?

Comment: @James_D I agree with you. But I'm don't know better atm. I just thought about delaying the predefined methods. But that would not solve my problem completly. Maybe I have to go with this now, because of a too big lack of knowledge regarding threads.

Comment: @James_D I seems not be that easy. Because although I start a new thread, that invokes the main method, the GUI is blocked while the thread is alive and will update after the thread finished. I added Thread.sleep to the predefined methods. Was that wrong? When I print out the current thread name in the for example the move() method it says, that it's still the JavaFX Application Thread.

Comment: I would simply not use threads at all, and I would not use `Thread.sleep()`. Use the animation API. See my answer (which is just an outline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an outline of how I might approach this, as the question really is too broad.

You are really asking how you can perform an animation that the user defines in code. (It's an animation because you are displaying a collection of frames, where each frame is defined by performing an operation, and there is a time gap between the operations.)

Consider creating a queue of operations to perform:

```
private class UI {

    private Queue<Runnable> operationQueue = new LinkedList<Runnable>();

    public Queue<Runnable> getOperationQueue() {
        return operationQueue();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now you can run an animation via a `Timeline` that periodically checks the queue, and if there's something in it, executes that operation:

```
public UI () {

    // set up ui, etc...

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e-> {
        if (! operationQueue.isEmpty()) {
            operationQueue.remove().run();
        }
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}
```

Now make your predefined basic methods private, and define public methods that submit those private methods to the queue:

```
public class BaseClass {

    private final UI ui = ... ;

    private void doMove() {
        // implementation here...
    }

    public void move() {
        ui.getOperationQueue().add(this::doMove);
    }

    private void doTakeHoney() {
        // implementation here...
    }

    public void takeHoney() {
        ui.getOperationQueue().add(this::doTakeHoney);
    }
}
```

Note there is actually no threading here at all. Everything is on the FX Application Thread; the timing is controlled by the `Timeline`.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds very good so far. Although my university gave me the task to use threads I will try this tomorrow. Will the GUI be blocked while the queue is active?

Comment: @JWo The UI will not be blocked. If you have to use threads you would need to insert `Thread.sleep()` between each call, wrap each actual call in `Platform.runLater(...)` and then execute the entire sequence on another thread.

Comment: Alright. I tried it now and it works very good. Canceling the main method also works. I think pause and resume will be possible too within a few minutes of work.
I don't really understand how to create threads in javafx, that work with the gui properly.
This helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I just discovered a new problem with this solution. I have three methods that would be added to the queue, but have return values (all boolean). The return value is important. The user can type in the GUI if (safeToGo) { move(); }.
Do you know how to add such methods to the queue without loosing the return value?
My first idea was to cache the results of the methods in member variables, reset them after certain actions and change the methods return type to void. but this looks not very good to me. I wonder if there is another way to deal wth this.

Comment: *can be added to the queue

Answer (score 0):

You can override the superclass's method which you want to run slowly, such as move():

```
void move() throws Exception {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  super.move();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

If you want to make your code can be controlled by UI button,then you will add some switches.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Maybe it is not clear enough, that my first code example is not written by me. That is what the user should write at runtime. In that way he should learn some basic programming.
And because of this he won't call methods from the super class or the sleep function.

Comment: Sorry,i don't understand your means just before. AOP may be help you to intercept the user's target method.

Comment: Can you tell me what AOP is? I'm not familiar with this abbreviation. Thank you.

Comment: @JWo AOP = "Aspect oriented programming". It's a technique to intercept method calls and add functionality to those calls. It requires an AOP framework to do that for you.

Comment: @simiam The problem with this suggestion is threading. Assuming `move()` changes the UI, you *must* execute `move()` on the FX Application Thread. On the other hand, you cannot block that thread, because you will make the UI unresponsive, and prevent it from actually re-rendering between calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is what is called `setTimeout` in javascript. Unfortunately, Java doesn't have such a method, and you have to rely on `Thread.sleep` to emulate it. Again, unfortunately, calling `Thread.sleep` on the JavaFX Application Thread will hang the application, so you need to use a JavaFX `Timeline`.

What you can do is declare an interface that will automate this for you:

```
class Delayed {
    private static long totalMillis;
    private static Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    static void setTimeout(Runnable r, long millis) {
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(new Duration(totalMillis += millis), event -> r.run()));
    }
    static void play() {
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

A method call

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

then becomes:

```
Delayed.setTimeout(() ->System.out.println("Hello World!"), 1000);
Delayed.play();
```

What I suggest is that you take the code you have (the one that's been entered by the user), and while it's still a `String`, that you convert all of the method calls to a `Delayed.setTimeout` call, like so:

```
final int TIMEOUT = 1000;
StringBuilder newCode = new StringBuilder();
Arrays.stream(codeString.split("\n")).forEach(s ->
{
    if (s.endsWith(";")) newCode.append("Delayed.setTimeout(() -> ")
            .append(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)) //remove ";"
            .append(", ").append(TIMEOUT)
            .append(");")
            .append("\n");
    else {
        newCode.append(s + "\n");
    }
});
newCode.append("Delayed.play();");
```

Of course, the `s.endsWith(";")` check is very naive, and won't work with things such as if statements, do/while loops, or statements on multiple lines. I couldn't find a more efficient way to check if a line was a complete statement, but this should work fine for very simple code such as the one that seems to be your concern.

**EDIT** Now working on JavaFX Application Thread.

Comment: Here's the problem though. The actual "target" runnable modifies the UI, so it *must* be executed on the UI thread. However, if you execute `Thread.sleep(...)` on that thread, you 1. make the UI unresponsive, and 2. prevent it actually rendering any updates. So you won't see all the individual steps. You simply can't do this by inserting calls to `Thread.sleep(...)`; you have to control the execution of the individual steps, either with an animation (easier, imho), or by wrapping the whole thing in another thread and wrapping the individual calls in `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: @James_D thanks for your comment. I saw that issue (see last paragraph of my answer), and judging by OP's attempt at delaying the method with a `Thread.sleep`, it wasn't very clear if the methods were running of the Application thread. I'm working on something, will edit this answer in 2 mins. cheers

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry you did mention that. I think it's pretty clear in the OP though that his methods update the UI ("visible as a canvas to the user").